# Mean with condition for multiple columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, mean, tapply

Let's use `mtcars` to explain the situation.

What I want to do is the same below for multiple columns. To have the mean of a column `qsec` (in the example) regarding another column with a specific value (4 and 6, in the example below). I'll compare the result later so maybe I would store the results in a vector

```
table(mtcars$cyl)
4  6  8
11  7 14

mean(mtcars$qsec[mtcars$cyl == 4], na.rm = T)
mean(mtcars$qsec[mtcars$gear == 4], na.rm = T)
```

I would like to check the means of `qsec` regarding the `cyl`, and let's say `gear` and `carb`, with the same "pattern" for the mean i.e. mean of observations with 4 and mean of observations 6. In the true dataset would be several columns that have the same set of numbers (2, 0 and 1). I'll compare the means of a column (in the example `qsec`) with observations 2 and 0.

I've tried to look at the functions like `tapply`, `apply`, `sapply`. But I'm stuck in having the condition in the mean applying for every column (at once).

Hope I made myself clear. 
Thank you!

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to know how to find the means of `qsec`, `gear`, and `carb` where `cyl` equals `4` or `6`?

Comment: Hi @phalteman, what I want is to have the means of `qsec` for the columns `gear`,`carb`,`cyl`, when they have number 4 in their observation. So it would be the mean of `qsec` when the observation in `gear` is equal 4. Then, another calc of men of `qsec` when the `gear` is 4, and so on.. for multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand you're looking for is the mean of `qsec` for each level of `cyl`, `gear`, and `carb` separately, not in combination. This code gets you that, but doesn't directly let you select specific levels of those factors. If you need to be able to do that second part, I think you should be able to tweak this to get there, but I'm not sure how...

```
apply(mtcars[,c("cyl","gear","carb")], 2, function(x) {
  aggregate(mtcars[,"qsec"],list(x),mean)
})
```

Output:

```
$cyl
  Group.1        x
1       4 19.13727
2       6 17.97714
3       8 16.77214

$gear
  Group.1      x
1       3 17.692
2       4 18.965
3       5 15.640

$carb
  Group.1        x
1       1 19.50714
2       2 18.18600
3       3 17.66667
4       4 16.96500
5       6 15.50000
6       8 14.60000
```

Answer (score 5):

The function you are looking for is `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(. ~ cyl, FUN=mean, data=mtcars[,c("cyl", "qsec", "gear", "carb")], 
          subset=cyl %in% c(4, 6)
          )

  cyl     qsec     gear     carb
1   4 19.13727 4.090909 1.545455
2   6 17.97714 3.857143 3.428571
```

In the function above `data=` is the data.frame. Here we only selected the wanted columns. And the `subset=` specifies which rows of the data to keep (in this case only cyl 4 and 6).

The formula `. ~ cyl` instructs to summarise all columns according to the `cyl` column.

Comment: In the subset, just use `cyl` instead of `mtcars$cyl`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I want is exactly this but in a way to do it for multiple columns at once like this:
`aggregate(. ~ cyl, FUN=mean, data=mtcars[,c("cyl", "qsec")], 
          subset=cyl %in% c(4, 6)
)`
First according `cyl`. Then, according `gear`, and so on...
`aggregate(. ~ gear, FUN=mean, data=mtcars[,c("gear", "qsec")], 
          subset=gear %in% c(4, 6)
)` 
Do you have an idea about how to apply this function in for more columns at once? I have several columns and would be great to find a way to do exactly this in a automatically way.

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)

mtcars[cyl %in% c(4, 6), .(mn_qsec = mean(qsec), 
                           mn_gear = mean(gear), 
                           mn_carb = mean(carb)), 
                      by = cyl]
```

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

On option is to use `dplyr::mutate_at` as OP wants to apply same function on multiple column. The solution will be as:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(c("qsec", "gear", "carb")), funs(mean), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  filter(cyl!=8)


# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# cyl  qsec  gear  carb
# <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  4.00  19.1  4.09  1.55
# 2  6.00  18.0  3.86  3.43
```